# Python Rock Paper Scissors game ( Loop for certain condition )

Tags: python, loops

I made a simple Rock Paper Scissors program, and I need to add a certain condition to this program.. I have to Let the
user play continuously until either the user or the computer wins more than two times in a row.I tried to find the answer in and out but unfortunately couldn't find it..

**First off I tried**

```
 gameOver = False
 playerScore = 0
 computerScore = 0
```

**and added**

```
while not gameOver:
    main()
    if playerScore == 2 :
        gameOver = True
```

and also added **playerScore += 1** to the if statements..
But wouldn't work ...
**any advise would help and much appreciated in advance.. cheers!**

### **And here is my code..**

```
import random
import sys


def main():
    player = input("Enter your choice in number (rock 1 / paper 2 / scissors 0) :")


    if (player == 0):
        player = "scissors"
    elif (player == 1):
        player = "rock"
    elif (player == 2):
        player = "paper"
    else:
    print("Invalid Input Quitting...")
    sys.exit(0)


    computer = random.randint(0,2)
    if (computer == 0):
        computer = "scissors"
    elif (computer == 1):
        computer = "rock"
    elif (computer == 2):
        computer = "paper"





    if (player == computer):
        print("Player is ",player, "Computer is ",computer," You Draw!")

    elif (player == "rock"):
        if (computer == "paper"):
            print("Player is ",player, "Computer is ",computer," You Lost!")


        else:
            print("Player is ",player, "Computer is ",computer," You Win!")



    elif (player == "paper"):
        if (computer == "rock"):
            print("Player is ",player, "Computer is ",computer," You Win!")


        else:
            print("Player is ",player, "Computer is ",computer," You Lost!")


    elif (player == "scissors"):
        if (computer == "rock"):
            print("Player is ",player, "Computer is ",computer," You Lost!")


        else:
            print("Player is ",player, "Computer is ",computer," You Win!")
```

Comment: Please correct indentation

Comment: Have a variable store the total number of games (in this case, 3), then if 1 player wins more than half of the total number, exit the main control loop. Also, please don't just say that something doesn't work. Fully explain out what isn't working correctly. Not only does this allow other people to help you easier, it requires you to think out the problem on a deeper level, which may lead you to answering you own question. I can't count how many times I typed out a question here, only to have the answer hit me in the face while I was thinking it through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your `main()` function return a value corresponding to who won, you could do:

```
gameOver = False
playerScore = 0
computerScore = 0

while not gameOver:
    player_wins = main()
    if player_wins == True:
        playerScore += 1
        computerScore = 0
    if player_wins == False:
        playerScore = 0
        computerScore += 1
    if player_wins == None:
        # Draw, do nothing to the scores
        pass
    if playerScore == 2 or computerScore == 2:
        print("Game over")
        print("  playerScore:", playerScore)
        print("  computerScore:", computerScore)
        gameOver = True
```

Note that I had it return `True` if the player won, `False` if the computer won,  and `None` if it was a draw.

Comment: @kylelee, [this](https://ideone.com/pLCHPv) is how I may have written the game -- some of the syntax will probably be confusing, but the structure may help you get an idea of how you can use multiple functions to avoid repeating yourself, large if/elif/else trees. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking only a schema:
(this is no true code)

```
Program starts:
gameover = False
lastWinner = ""
Loop until gameover == True
    ask for player answer
    make the random choice of the computer
    winner = "asigned winner"
    if lastWinner == winner:
        gameover = True
        Print something cool about who is the winner
    else:
        lastWinner = winner
```

Comment: this helps!! thank you.. and How do I find out who won the game 3 times in a row ???

Comment: You should store that information: On OOC you may put a map to represent the board of the game, or a property on the players that would reset if the other contestant wins contestant

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting an error when attempting to modify the globals, but from your example it's not entirely clear.
If you try to modify `playerScore` or `computerScore` in your main() method, it'll yell at you unless you have a statement like:

```
global computerScore
```

before you modify it.

Also, avoid repeating yourself in your code.  I was able to trim much of your code out by using the following:

```
computerWins = False

print "Player is %s; Computer is %s" % (computer, player)

if (player == computer):
  print "Draw"
  return 0
elif (player == "rock"):
  computerWins = computer == "paper"
elif (player == "paper"):
  computerWins = computer == "scissors"
elif (player == "scissors"):
  computerWins = computer == "rock"

if computerWins:
  global computerScore
  computerScore = computerScore + 1
  print "Computer wins"
else:
  global playerScore
  playerScore = playerScore + 1
  print "You win"
```